# Why are titles showing up as boxes?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, title

The titles of some of the question I view are showing up as just boxes

[image: Title Boxes]

I'm running Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3 and Google Chrome (18.0.1025.142 m).  Let me know if you need more information.

**Update 2** - So something in Chrome appears to have died.  I restarted chrome and the problem went away.  Sorry for taking up peoples time investigating this.

**Update** - So this appears to be related to the zoom level.  On my PC, its the `default` zoom level.  Doing `Ctrl + 0` will take you to the default zoom level.  All other zoom levels result in the text being displayed and not the boxes.

So others dont have to pick through the comments.  This only happens on **some** of the questions.  The image question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029597/serialport-write-method-hanging-timeout-not-fired-in-c-sharp/10029772#10029772).

It does NOT show up as boxes with IE 8.0.6001.18702 on the same PC

It does NOT show up as boxes with Firefox 3.6.14 on the same PC

If I edit the title and type `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` and all I got were boxes. No characters at all

I do not have anything `Enabled` under `chrome://flags`

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with your computer's fonts, e.g.

Comment: Link please.. Or is this for all titles?? Then you probably deleted a font..

Comment: Its only for some questions.  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029597/serialport-write-method-hanging-timeout-not-fired-in-c-sharp) is the one from the picture I posted

Comment: norepo - Chrome 18 on ubuntu 10.4

Comment: Norepro, Chrome 20.0.1091.0 on Windows 8.6.2. Does it work on any other browser?

Comment: @minitechη - It works with IE 8.0.6001.18702 on the same PC

Comment: *Works* means you **can** or **can't** reproduce it?

Comment: @Lix - Sorry, works meaning it does NOT show up as boxes.  I see the title as words

Comment: Even this question shows up as boxes to me.  If I edit it, as I type, it just shows boxes.  Not sure if thats helpful.

Comment: Try typing out all the letters, see if any work. I've had a similar issue before, actually.

Comment: Reason: Unicode hates you ‮‮uoy setah edocinU

Comment: @minitechη - Ok, I'll try that.  It produces text and not the boxes in Firefox 3.6.14 on the same PC

Comment: No repro FF10 Win7.

Comment: @minitechη - Ok, so I typed `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` and all I got were boxes.  No characters at all.

Comment: Okay, it's not the same problem then :) Mine was about random characters disappearing, also in Chrome under XP. Do you have any `chrome://flags` turned on?

Comment: @minitechη - All the options are either disabled (not supported) or say `Enabled`, so I'm assuming they are all off.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your `chrome://flags` page please?

Comment: @minitechη - Yup, standby, it will probably be couple pictures, a long list

Comment: @minitechη - Is there a way to upload a pdf, might be easier.  But on a side note, I think I found the problem.  It seems to be related to the font size.  If I do Ctrl + scroll, it changes to text.  There seems to be one setting that doesnt work.  I'm trying to figure out  the size.

Comment: For me, its six scroll ticks up from the smallest font size.

Comment: Uh-oh, six is the normal zoom level. Odd.

Comment: @SwDev Ctrl+0 should get you to default zoom.

Comment: @ManishEarth - It does, and thats where the boxes show up.  Every other scroll position (for the font resize) shows the text how its supposed to.

Comment: @minitechη - So do you think I somehow lost the specific font/size for this?  Is there someway to check or try a different font/size setup to see if it will work at the normal zoom level? Or maybe reload the fonts in Chrome since the issue doesnt show up in IE or Firefox (retested knowing its the zoom, and they are ok)

Comment: @SwDevMan81: That's strange--most probably you deleted a size of the relevant font. Or Chrome's millisecond-updates blew something up for you (can happen if your connection dies at precisely the right moment). Wait till it updates again (use [Chrome Canary](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=chrome%20canary&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftools.google.com%2Fdlpage%2Fchromesxs&ei=p7t9T5fZKYis8AShwNXzDA&usg=AFQjCNFbMyJnUB4vCTWlnmx_aS7Jl1HJKQ) in the meantime--it runs the extreme latest Chrome version without overwriting your current install). ‮‮  uoy setah edocinU ,rO

Comment: @ManishEarth - I think you are right, something in Chrome I think just died.  I restarted and the problem seemed to go away.  Sorry for taking up everyones time...

Comment: @SwDev My condolences to whoever died :P